# Do I need to send all parameters with each hit using Google Analytics Measurement Protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I wonder if I need to send all parameters with each hit, or if some of the parameters are 'cached' in the current session. I.e. do I require to send the resolution, view port, etc. with each hit, or is it enough to send those once per session?

I can't find any source that confirms what behaviour it it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which specific parameters you mean, but the fields you specify when you create your tracker apply to all hits for that tracker. See the GA documentation section called [Specifying fields at creation time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#specifying_fields_at_creation_time). More specifically the [send documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#send) states (emphasis mine),

> The fields that are sent are the values specified in the ...fields parameters and fieldsObject, **merged with the fields currently stored on the tracker**.

Comment: And of course campaign parameters (medium, source, campaign, term, content).